# Summing values until date changes

Tags: r

I would like to sum up numbers in one column as long as they have the same date associated with them. The problem is that the dates do not change on a regular basis. 
For example my data set would look like this:

```
Date          Amount          
12/15/2016   2300
12/15/2016   2300
12/15/2016   2300
12/15/2016   2300
12/15/2016   2300
12/15/2016   2300 
12/15/2016   2300
12/15/2016   2300
12/19/2016   2300
12/19/2016   2300
12/19/2016   2300
12/19/2016   2300
12/19/2016   2300
12/19/2016   2300
12/19/2016   2300
12/19/2016   2300
12/19/2016   2300
12/19/2016   2300
12/19/2016   2300
12/06/2016   2300 
12/06/2016   2300 
12/06/2016   2300 
12/06/2016   2300
12/06/2016   2300
12/06/2016   2300
12/06/2016   2300
12/06/2016   2300
12/06/2016   2300
12/06/2016   2300
12/06/2016   2300
12/06/2016   2300
```

The actual amounts are all different. The output should be the summed up amounts in one column and the corresponding dates in another.  I thought about using group_by or a for loop but I got stuck with both of those since I am pretty new to R. Found a few similar questions but could not find any that answer my question. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome. With packages dplyr/tidyverse you could certainly get your work done through groub_by(Date) and summarise(Amount = sum(ammount).
Yet, it is expected that you point what you have tried and where did that go wrong. I would suggest you familiarize yourself with these guides: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `aggregate(data$Amount, list(data$Date), sum)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(Date = c("12/15/2016", "12/15/2016", "12/15/2016", "12/15/2016", "12/15/2016", "12/15/2016", "12/15/2016", "12/15/2016", "12/19/2016", "12/19/2016", "12/19/2016", "12/19/2016", "12/19/2016", "12/19/2016", "12/19/2016", "12/19/2016", "12/19/2016", "12/19/2016", "12/19/2016", "12/06/2016", "12/06/2016", "12/06/2016", "12/06/2016", "12/06/2016", "12/06/2016", "12/06/2016", "12/06/2016", "12/06/2016", "12/06/2016", "12/06/2016", "12/06/2016"), Amount = c(2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L)), row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), Amount = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))

df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(amount_sum = sum(Amount))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Date       amount_sum
#>   <chr>           <int>
#> 1 12/06/2016      27600
#> 2 12/15/2016      18400
#> 3 12/19/2016      25300
```

Created on 2018-06-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).